# Python PIL issues on Windows 7 x64

Tags: python, windows-7, python-imaging-library

This is my 1st time working on coding and such so all of this seems complicated but the more I'm learning the easier it's becoming. Anyways I was trying to learn this tut so I can get familiar with Python, which a friend told me is easy (the software, not the tut--I found this on my own as a project to work with):

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/how-to-build-a-python-bot-that-can-play-web-games/?search_index=3

I had issues with the PIL due to the fact that I have a desktop Windows 7 x64 that this is installed in. 1st it wouldn't find Python so I had to dl Pillow from another site which worked just fine. Now when I get to the 1st action of the tut I keep getting a error telling me that it can't identify the ImageGrab or locate it, which is frustrating. Has anyone had this issue before and if so what is your solution to this problem?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far plus the full error message. Mind reading is a difficult business. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the code I punched in:

```
import ImageGrab
import os
import time

def screenGrab():
    box = ()
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) +
'.png', 'PNG')

def main():
    screenGrab()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here's the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dwayne\Desktop\quickGrab.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ImageGrab
ImportError: No module named ImageGrab
```

> > > 

ok so now I'll make the adjustment that cgo suggested:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import os
import time

def screenGrab():
    box = ()
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) +
'.png', 'PNG')

def main():
    screenGrab()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and all I got was a blank shell. Maybe I did something right but I thought the snapshot of the screen would pop up just like in the tutorial. I'll keep working at it until I get it right or get another solution from somewhere.

And I don't get this rating system on here and other forums but rating me negatively doesn't help nor make sense seeing that I wasn't being rude. Maybe you people should spend less time on Facebook and other social networks judging people over stupid stuff and actually HELP. Rating a simple question is irrelevant unless it's so simple even a caveman can figure it out.

Comment: Ok figured part of it out after doing a bit of searching for it to access a web browser:         import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('image.png')      it just opens the default viewer but it did something. Now to figure out how to incorporate this into the script/source code/formula/whatever it's called for this tutorial.............thanx for the springboard, kinda. :D